# Streaming SQL- How to get last record in simple tumbling window aggregation

Tags: sql, streaming, aggregation, amazon-kinesis

**Environment** - AWS Kinesis Analytics (but I can take any streaming SQL concept suggested and apply it to my environment)

I have source data like this that continuously streams in:

```
epoc_timestamp  baic_id station floor       ap
1552314547      alex    bloor   platform    be-ye12
1552314548      alex    bloor   platform    be-ye12
1552314549      alex    bloor   platform    ye-ab70
1552314550      alex    bloor   platform    ye-ab70
1552314551      alex    bloor   platform    ye-ab70
1552314555      alex    bloor   platform    ye-ab70
1552314559      alex    bloor   platform    ge-ye30
```

I am looking to get the LAST "ap" recorded, partitioned by baic_id (there are multiple, not just "alex" as seen above) and grouped into 10 second windows.  So the result from the data above would look like this:

```
epoc_timestamp  baic_id station floor       ap
1552314540      alex    bloor   platform    ye-ab70
1552314550      alex    bloor   platform    ge-ye30
```

**Note**: While this is relatively easy in standard SQL with something like

*LAST_VALUE(ap) OVER (PARTITION BY baic_id ORDER by epoc_timestamp RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)*

I am using streaming SQL which means there is no "end" to the stream and Kinesis Analytics will not allow the use of UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING.  So if I use LAST_VALUE it only grabs the CURRENT value as it cannot see the following rows.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked almost 5 years ago.. Let me answer it using new streaming SQL engine: https://github.com/timeplus-io/proton

```sql
SELECT window_start, baic_id, latest(epoc_timestamp), latest(station), latest(floor), latest(ap) 
FROM tumble(stream,10s) PARTITION BY baic_id GROUP BY window_start, baic_id
```

`tumble(stream,10s)` is to create a tumble window for every 10 second.

`PARTITION BY baic_id` is to create sub-streams to track watermarks for each key

`latest(col)` is to get the latest value in that window. It's a special aggregation function.